# set theory GRE question

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $S_0=\{A,B\}$, where $A,B$ are subsets of some set $M$. Define $S_{i+1}$ inductively to be the collection of subsets of $M$ that are the form $C \cup D, C \cap D, M \backslash C$ where $C,D \in S_i$. What is the largest cardinality of $\bigcup S_i$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ ? so it is $16$. I tried actually writing the sets down and it gets nasty. Is there a faster combinatorics way of doing this? is it just $2^{k+1}$ where $k$ is cardinality of my $S_0$ (or number of operations)?

Comment: Maybe $2^{2^k}$ rather than $2^{k+1}$.

Comment: but then if $k=3$ it wouldnt work, or are you assuming $k$ is number of elements in my $S_0$. I thought 2 was for 2 elements and $k$ for number of operations. i.e., union, intersection, and comp.

Comment: Suppose you start with three sets $A,B,C$. Then there are $8$ kinds of points: a point may be in $A$ or not in $A$, in $B$ or not in $B$, in $C$ or not in $C$. Then you get $2^8=256$ different sets by deciding which kinds of points you want in your set. Now you have to show that each of those $2^{2^k}$ sets can be constructed using the given operations. And of course that no other sets can be obtained but that's pretty obvious.

Comment: I agree with bof, I think the idea is that with the given operations you can differentiate between $2^k$ sets of points, and then choose whether to include or exclude each set, which gives you $2^{2^k}$

Comment: You wrote "$k$ is cardinality of my $S_0$" and I was following that. The operations are fixed.

Comment: yeah you're right I keep mixing those us sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $K$ of $S_i$, i.e. a subset of M, is determined by which elements of $M$ are in it. By construction, whether $k\in K$ depends only on two questions: whether $k \in A$, and whether $k\in B$. So, we might as well pretend $A = \{a,c\}$, $B = \{b,c\}$, and $M = \{a,b,c,d\}$. Here, you can think of "a" as representing "elements of $A$ that are not in $B$" and "c" as "elements in both $A$ and $B$", and so on.

Then you can play with the induction and see pretty easily that every combination of $a,b,c,$ and $d$ can be made using the "boolean operations" of union, intersection, and complement. That is, $S_i$ eventually becomes the entire power set $\mathcal{P}(M)$, which has $2^4 = 16$ elements. So the $4$ here is coming from the $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ that I use to represent the four ways the element can relate to the sets $A$ and $B$.

You can try thinking about this for three subsets, $A, B$, and $C$. Then the relevant questions are membership in $A$, $B$, and $C$, which leads to eight different possibilities (concretely, think about $A = \{a,d,e,g\}$, $B = \{b,d,f,g\}$, $C = \{c,e,f,g\}$ and $M = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$)

Answer (score 1):

1. Note that there is a simple absolute limit for the cardinality. $ \cup S_i \subset \mathcal{P}(M) $, so at most you can get the cardinality of the powerset of $M$.
2. Now draw a Venn diagram of $A$ and $B$. Assuming they intersect, M is divided in four regions, namely $A-B$, $B-A$, $A \cap B $ and $ M \setminus (A \cup B) $. Try to figure out how the members of $ S_i $ are related to these four regions.

Comment: I thought its complements of $A,B$ with respect to $M$? you're making the assumption $A \cup B = M$, no?

Comment: The basic idea is that two sets $A$ and $B$ divide the points of M in (at most) two categories: points only in A, points only in B, points in both A and B and points in neither A or B. Call these sets E,F,G,H. Can you show that at any step of the construction if a non-empty set belongs in $S_i$ it can be written as a union of $ E,~F,~G,~H$?

Comment: so $2$ to the power of $E,F,G,H$? so $2^4$? because that's the number os possibilities you get out of the operations?

Comment: Yes, that's why you generally get $2^{2^k}$,. If $A$ and $B$ do not have points in common you only get $2^3$.